# Как задать размер текста в ui toolkit, чтобы на всех разрешениях экрана он смотрелся одинаково?

Tags: unity3d, ui

Если например создать текстовый элемент ui в канвасе, установить для тестового блока привязку к верхнему краю и растягивание по ширине, то на любых экранах этот текст будет визуально занимать одинаковую часть пространства. Хоть на 800x600, хоть 1900x1080.
Но как такое сделать через ui toolkit я не могу понять.
Я только начал изучать ui в unity. И с одной стороны мне нравится что при построении ui на канвасе текст ведёт себя предсказуемо на разных разрешениях, с другой стороны меня привлекает в ui toolkit принцип верстки, который отдаленно походит на html вёрстку. Но меня останавливает то что на разных разрешениях элементы (особенно текст) имеют совершенно разные пропорции.
Текст на маленьких экранах слишком крупный, а на больших слишком мелкий. Я пробовал задавать размер текста в процентах, но это не помогло.
Плюс очень не хватает vh и vw единиц измерения, которые например есть в css. А проценты это не всегда то что нужно.
Подскажите как же всё-таки сделать чтобы текст в ui toolkit меню смотрелся одинаково на разных разрешениях экрана.

Comment: А ui toolkit можно использовать с canvas? Я просто создавал в сцене ui toolkit элемент и назначал на него uxml.

Comment: Нет нельзя, я фигню написал.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, поискав в инете я понял что ui toolkit - не лучший способ сделать инвентарь и он считается устаревший, вот тут я нашёл довольно подробный видосик о другом пакете для UI https://youtu.be/c6pqbSutOQs

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Как раз таки UI Toolkit это и есть новый способ, а через канвас это старый способ. Но по всей видимости UI Toolkit еще очень сырой, поэтому не все в нем можно сделать.